# How to add NSMUtable sictionary into a NSMUtableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, ios6, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMUtableArray` and a `NSMutableDictionary`. My code gets objects from an `NSArray` into a `NSMUtableDictionary`. Then add those `NSMUtableDictionary` objects into an `NSMutableArray`

this is my code

`

```
  NSArray *sqlAllarray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dir_bill"]];

    for (NSMutableDictionary *alldataDict in sqlAllarray ) {

        paydate2=[fmtDate2 dateFromString:[alldataDict valueForKey:@"bill_dateDue"]];

        if ([paydate1 compare:paydate2]==NSOrderedDescending || [paydate2 compare:paydate1]==NSOrderedSame) {


            appDel.untillPaydayArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//addObject:[alldataDict copy]];
            [appDel.untillPaydayArray addObject:[alldataDict copy]];
        }

    }`
```

But it takes only the last `NSMUtableDictionary` data into the `NSMUtableArray`. How can I solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new mutable array during every iteration of the loop. There are a few other issues in this code. Try this:

```
1. NSArray *sqlAllarray = [sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dir_bill"];

2. appDel.untillPaydayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

3. for (NSMutableDictionary *alldataDict in sqlAllarray ) {
4.    paydate2=[fmtDate2 dateFromString:[alldataDict valueForKey:@"bill_dateDue"]];

5.    if ([paydate1 compare:paydate2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
6.        [appDel.untillPaydayArray addObject:[alldataDict copy]];
7.    }
8.}
```

1) No need for the extra NSArray creation.

2) You need to initialize the array once, before the loop. You had this in the loop so each iteration resulted in the array being reset.

5) No need to check for descending and equal. Just check for ascending.